# Changing the order of "Restrict"ed pointers yield different assemblies

Tags: c, pointers

I was browsing [Wikipedia/Restrict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict), and found that

> The compiler can e.g. rearrange the code, first loading all memory locations, then performing the operations before committing the results back to memory.

Later, I noticed that

```
void updatePtrs(long int *restrict ptrA, long int *ptrB, long int *val)
{
  *ptrA += *val;
  *ptrB += *val;
}
```

and

```
void updatePtrs(long int *restrict ptrA, long int *ptrB, long int *val)
{
  *ptrB += *val;
  *ptrA += *val;
}
```

don't yield the same assembly with `-Ofast`. This applies for both GCC and Clang.

You can experiment with them [here](https://godbolt.org/g/wZiHJp) and [here](https://godbolt.org/g/VEFGke)

Why do they have different assemblies? Was this expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `ptrB` nor `val` are `restrict`, so `ptrB` and `val` could point to the same `long`. When they do, the order of `*ptrA += *val;` and `*ptrB += *val;` matters.

Even if all pointers were `restrict`, the compiler would only be allowed, not required, to rearrange the operations.